# Finding rational number from ternary expansion

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Find the rational numbers whose ternary expansion is given by

$0_{\dot 3}21\overline{21}$

How do you find this?

So far I got $\frac{2}{3^1} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{2}{3^3} + \frac{1}{3^4}+......$

Comment: Isn't this the same as $0_{\dot 3}\overline{21}$? Do you know how to find the value of $0.\overline{123}$ in base 10?

Comment: So far I got $\frac{2}{3^1} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{2}{3^3} + \frac{1}{3^4}+......$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is base 3, every single position to the right of "decimal" ("tresimal?) point is 1/3, every two positions is $(1/3)^2= (1/9)$.

So $0.21= 2/3+ 1/9= 6/9+ 1/9= 7/9$.

$0.212121...= 7(1/9)+ 7(1/9)^2+ 7(1/9)^3+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$  That's a geometric sequence, $\sum ar^{n-1}$ with "starting value" $a= 7/9$ and "common ratio" r= 1/9.  The infinite sum is $\frac{a}{1- r}= \frac{\frac{7}{9}}{1- \frac{1}{9}}= \frac{7}{9}\frac{1}{\frac{8}{9}}= \frac{7}{9}\frac{9}{8}= \frac{7}{8}$

Comment: Ah I was wondering where they got the 7 in the numerator from!

Answer (score 0):

Your sum equals
\begin{align*}
2\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac1{3^{2k+1}}
+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{3^{2k}}
&=\frac23\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac1{9^k}
+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{9^k}-1\\
&=\left(\frac23+1\right)\frac1{1-\frac19}-1\\
&=\frac53\cdot\frac98-1\\
&=\frac{14}{8}\\
&= \frac{7}{4}
\end{align*}